# Run windows executable from python script with multiple arguments

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I am working on a program that will find some files and provide the file information to a NSIS script.  The NSIS script accepts the command line as follows

```
makensis.exe /DON="This is one" /DOD="c:\path1\path2 to dir\path 3" scriptfile.nsi
```

The values of the switches will change on each execution of the program.  I have tried to get this to execute using subprocess.call and subprocess.Popen.  The issue I am having has to do with quoting.

First of all the subprocess calls seem to put the entire argument statement between double quotes making NSIS see them as one argument.  Second I am having some difficulty getting the individual  switches properly quoted on the command line.  Here is a snippet of what my program currently looks like.

```
subprocess.Popen([setup.profile['NSISExe'], ' /DON="' + setup.profile['DESC'] + '" /DOD="' + setup.profile['InstallDir'] + \
   '" /DMT="' + app.machine_type.get() + '" /DSD="' + os.path.join(WinShellVar.LOCAL_APPDATA, 'MLC CAD', appname) + \
   '" /DXV=X6 ' + setup.profile['NSISScript']])
```

And here is the output from NSIS

```
    Can't open script " /DON="Mastercam X6 Standard" /DOD="C:\Users\John\Desktop" /D
MT="mill" /DSD="C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\MLC CAD\mcdeftool" /DXV=X6 bin\packa
ge.002.nsi"
```

As you can see I am using a mixed bag of data, getting some bits for dicts and some from class calls *(be easy on me if my terms are somewhat incorrect, I have been learning python for about 4 days now, correct me please just nicely).*  If using this data like this is "unpythonic" let me know.

Looking forward to your input

Comment: As a note of style, you don't need a trailing `\ ` to continue a line in python if there is some sort of unterminated bracket hanging around.  e.g. `( [ {`

Comment: re: my previous comment -- Further explanation can be found in the python [style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*disclaimer -- I don't use windows*

---

I think you probably want something like:

```
subprocess.Popen([setup.profile['NSISExe'], '/DON=' + setup.profile['DESC'],
                  '/DOD=' + setup.profile['InstallDir'],
                  '/DMT=' + app.machine_type.get(),
                  '/DSD=' + os.path.join(WinShellVar.LOCAL_APPDATA, 'MLC CAD', appname), 
                  '/DXV=X6',
                  setup.profile['NSISScript']])
```

When the shell reads the commandline, it splits on non-quoted, non-escaped whitespace.  When you pass a list to `Popen`, it expects the list elements to be the way it would look after the shell split the arguments.  The other option is to pass a string (instead of a list) *exactly* as you would put it into the windows shell and pass `shell=True` to `Popen`.  But that method isn't preferred as it is much more vulnerable to shell-injection insecurities.

Comment: This works! I see the problem was I was trying to give python to much help.  What an awesome language, loving it so far!

Comment: @JohnMcCord -- It only gets better :).  I've been working with it for maybe 2 years now and I grow to enjoy it more and more each day :)